# Как остановить SetInteval при появлении элемента на странице?

Tags: javascript

Сделал кнопку, которая запускает Setinterval, который запускает функцию, в которой есть тоже setinterval, который должен запускаться если нет элемента с классом myclass, если есть, то запускается не должен и должен останавливаться когда он появится. Добавил функцию для добавления div c нужным классом. И когда он появляется, Setinterval 0 всё равно не останавливается. Как его остановить?

```
   <div class="panel">
      <div class="stop_interval">
    
    .mbtn{
    display: inline-block;
    font: 14px/24px "Pt Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 0.08s linear;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-decoration: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fb5b49 0%, #ee320a 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 0 #a70301 inset;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: none;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 25px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0px 12px;}
    
    
    function CreatMyDiv() { 
        
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "Hello"; 
    div.className = 'myclass';
    div.style.cssText = "position: relative;  top: 50px;  left: 60px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;"; 
      document.querySelector(".panel").appendChild(div);    
        
    }
    
    function myAuto() { 
    let intId0, intId1;
    const Cell0 = document.querySelector('.myclass');
      
    if (!Cell0) {
      CreatMyDiv()
      // Если есть элемент с классом "myclass._my"
        // Запускаем SetInterval, если он еще не запущен
        if (!intId0) {
          intId0 = setInterval(function() {
          
            // Ваш код, который нужно выполнить периодически
        
            console.log('SetInterval 0 запущен');
         }, 1000); // Здесь 1000 - интервал в миллисекундах (1 секунда)
        }
     } else if (Cell0) {
        // Если есть элемент с классом "myclass" и SetInterval запущен, останавливаем его
       clearInterval(intId0);
        intId0 = null;
        console.log('SetInterval 0 остановлен');
      }
    }
          
    
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   var myButton = document.createElement('div');
   var oldHref = document.location.href;
   var bodyList = document.querySelector("body");
   var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (oldHref != document.location.href) {BtnCreate(); }});  

  function BtnCreate() {
    oldHref = document.location.href;
    myButton.id = 'btnmy';
    myButton.type = 'button';
    myButton.textContent = 'Старт';
    myButton.className = 'mbtn';
    myButton.style.cssText = "position: absolute; border-style: none; top: 3px;\
    left: 3px; width: 45px; height: 25px; outline: none; padding: 0px 12px;"; 

var isRunning = false;
 myButton.onclick = () => { 
  if (isRunning) {

    clearInterval(mytimer);  

    isRunning = false;
  myButton.textContent = 'Старт';
  console.log('SetInterval mytimer ОСТАНОВЛЕН');
  } else {
 mytimer = setInterval( myAuto, 1000);
    isRunning = true;
   myButton.textContent = 'Стоп';
 console.log('SetInterval mytimer ЗАПУЩЕН');
  }}
  const container = document.querySelector(".panel");
  container.appendChild(myButton); }
  observer.observe(bodyList, { childList: true, subtree: true });
  BtnCreate();
});
```

Comment: А на кой вообще тут все эти интервалы? В текущем коде они абсолютно бессмысленны

Comment: Алексей Шиманский как понять бессысленные? Они же выполняют переодически нужные мне функции.  Эта кнопка добавляется на сайт через расшерение браузерное. Хочу что-бы с помощью этой кнопки выполнялись одинаковые действия, что-бы мышью не кликать много-много раз.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский мне бы сделать так, что-бы intId0  запускался при отсутсвии класса .myclass, не запускался при его наличии и останавливался если класс .myclass появится. Задача вроде не сложная, но не для меня)

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const el = document.createElement('button');
  el.classList.add('my-class');
  el.textContent = 'кнопка';

  document.body.appendChild(el);
},1_000);

// Выбираем целевой элемент
const target = document.querySelector('body');

// Конфигурация observer (за какими изменениями наблюдать)
const config = {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
};

// Колбэк-функция при срабатывании мутации
const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
    const target = document.querySelector('.my-class');
    if (target) {
        const el = document.createElement('h2');
        el.textContent = 'Кнопка появилась';
        document.body.appendChild(el);
        observer.disconnect();
    }
};

// Создаём экземпляр наблюдателя с указанной функцией колбэка
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Начинаем наблюдение за настроенными изменениями целевого элемента
observer.observe(target, config);
```

В данном случае стоит использовать MutationObserver
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Олег, так зачем мне кнопка? Кнопка у меня и так есть и работает. Мне нужно что-бы когда я нажимаю на кнопу запускался Setinterval, который запускает переодически функцию myAuto. Это у меня работает. А вот сама функция myAuto работает не так. Она должна запустить Setinterval, когда нет myclass, не запускать если есть myclass и остановить если он появится на странице.